# The draggable effect do not show the second time

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, drag-and-drop, jquery-events

I am using the jQuery UI to get a UI effect something like drag element to another a element and replace 'width','height','position' width each other.

See this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/strangeline/cnchK/).

I think things just became really weird to me:

When first drag an element,it works just fine, but when the second time I am dragging the same element, the things just happened wired: draggable effect seems no long work,but when drop all the code in the callback function will still run.

Try it yourself,and you will find out what I am talking about.

I have debugged this all this night, help me please please! I really really do not what's wrong with the code!

Comment: It's the  "position":' ' clause you have used that's causing the problem. But if I remove it, the layouts go crazy. You should find a workaround to fix those layouts.

Comment: @TWickz yeah, i have run though all the jquery ui APi doc, now simply use "helper : 'clone'" in the draggable method will solve all the problem.see the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/strangeline/cnchK/11/)

Comment: I just figured it out as well! Nice work getting this done yourself and thanks for posting the question. I certainly had some fun with this.

Comment: Yeah I was also wondering how can be this done, just like @TWickz - nice solution strangeline! :-)

Comment: It takes two days to accept your own answer :-)

Comment: @TWickz thank you! i really do not know this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

run though all the jquery ui APi doc, now simply use "helper : 'clone'" in the draggable method will solve all the problem.see the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/strangeline/cnchK/11/)